# Taking data from multiple files and moving to one file

Tags: java, file-io

I some code that takes a file called `wonder1.txt` and writes the date in that file to another file. Lets say I have more files like `wonder2.txt`, `wonder3.txt`, `wonder4.txt`. How do I write the rest in the same file.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class alice {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    String fileName = ("/Users/DAndre/Desktop/Alice/wonder1.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
    try {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String line = br.readLine();

        while (line != null) {
            stringBuilder.append(line);
            stringBuilder.append("\n");
            line = br.readLine();
        }


        /**
         * Pass original file content as string to another method which
         * creates new file with same content.
         */
        newFile(stringBuilder.toString());
    } finally {
        br.close();
    }


  }

  public static void newFile(String fileContent) {
    try {
        String newFileLocation = "/Users/DAndre/Desktop/Alice/new1.txt";
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(newFileLocation);
        writer.write(fileContent);//Writes original file content into new file
        writer.close();
        System.out.println("File Created");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have list of files, then you can loop over them one by one. Your current code moves inside the loop.
The easier way would be to put all the files in one folder and read from it.

Something like this :

```
File folder = new File("/Users/DAndre/Desktop/Alice");

    for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
        String fileName = fileEntry.getAbsolutePath();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
        try {
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            String line = br.readLine();

            while (line != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(line);
                stringBuilder.append("\n");
                line = br.readLine();
            }


            /**
             * Pass original file content as string to another method which
             * creates new file with same content.
             */
            newFile(stringBuilder.toString());
        } finally {
            br.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: All the files are in one folder

Comment: I dont under this part: for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
    String fileName = fileEntry.getName();

Comment: my bad that.. Edited it again. So the variable 'folder' represent the folder where you kept your files. Make sure the file you write is in a different folder, otherwise it will read it and rewrite the content to it.

Comment: I got this error:Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: .DS_Store (No such file or directory)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:120)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:79)
 at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:41)
 at alice.main(alice.java:16)

Comment: what is the folder path on your system.. does this exists - /Users/DAndre/Desktop/Alice?

Comment: Yes, the code was working just fine for one file so the folder is there, but when I did what you just said I got that error.

Comment: my bad again. Need to get absolute path - fileEntry.getAbsolutePath(). Tested the code on my system it works